# video shows black screen at start

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

i am recording video using surfaceviwe on button click but at the starting it shows black screen. i don't knows where i am wrong.. i have tired lots of thing but do not  work.

```
       private void initRecorder(Surface surface) throws IOException
      if(mCamera == null) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.unlock();

    if(mMediaRecorder == null)
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface);
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    String pathname=createDirectoryAndSaveFile();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("shared", 
     Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("videopath",pathname);
    editor.commit();
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pathname);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
    //mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1920,1080);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280,720);
    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    mInitSuccesful = true;
}
```

i want at the start camera shows preview

Comment: use the CameraX library.

Comment: thanks for your res.  i have one wrong thing in that code i forgot to add       mCamera.startPreview();  after  previewdisplay method..now everything works fine for me